# Closure and interior in infinite products of sets

Tags: general-topology

If $X,Y$ are topological spaces containing subsets $A,B$ respectively, then we know that in the product space $X \times Y$:

(1) $(A \times B)^\circ = A^\circ \times B^\circ$, where $^\circ$ denotes the interior operation, and

(2) $\overline{(A \times B)} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, where $\overline{\cdot}$ denotes the closure operation.

An exercise from Willard's *General Topology* claims that (2) can be extended to infinite products but (1) can be extended only to finite products.

As far as I can tell, the proof that (2) extends to infinite products is just the obvious extension of the proof from the case where we show that the equality holds for the product of two sets. But I've also convinced myself that the proof for (1) can be extended, similarly.

Assuming the statement in the exercise is correct, this cannot be the case, so I must be misunderstanding something. Would anyone be able to explain (with a proof or illustrative example) why (1) can only be extended to finite products?

Comment: To prove (1)  for infinite products, you would need to know that an infinite intersection of open sets is open.  Usually false.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n=\Bbb R$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and let $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$. Let $A_n=(0,1)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and let $A=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$. Clearly $\operatorname{int}A_n=A_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{int}A_n=A$, but $\operatorname{int}A=\varnothing$.

To see this, recall that the product topology has a base consisting of all sets of the form $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open in $X_n$, **and $U_n=X_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$**. Clearly none of these basic open sets will fit inside $A$, so $A$ cannot contain any non-empty open set.

What happens in this specific examples shows exactly why (1) cannot in general be extended to infinite products: as long as the factor spaces contain non-empty open sets that are not the whole space, you can construct a similar counterexample.

Comment: Following the comment to the Q by @GEdgar , let $B_{n,m}=\Bbb R$ when $n\ne m$ and let $B_{m,m}=\Bbb R$ \ $A_m.$ And let $C_n=\prod_{m\in \Bbb N}B_{n,m}.$ Then $X$ \ $A$ $=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n$ is an infinite union of closed sets, but is not closed. A similar calculation for a product of closed sets yields a complement (in $X$) that is an infinite union of open sets.